# How to use Redux and MobX on same project

Tags: react-native, redux, mobx

Both Redux and MobX seem to have their own custom 'Provider' which makes using both in the same project, not possible.
Did any one manage to solve this some how?

Comment: Why would you have both of them?

Comment: Good question, because I would like to migrate to MobX, step by step

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested it but if you want to avoid naming collisions you could give custom names when importing those `Providers`

```
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux'
import { Provider as MobxProvider} from 'mobx-react'


// ...

ReactDOM.render(
  (<ReduxProvider store={yourReduxStore}>
    <MobxProvider someStore={yourMobxStore}>
      <App />
    </MobxProvider>
  </ReduxProvider>
 ),
 document.querySelector('#yourMountingPoint')
)
```